# Child process is unexpectedly killed without error output

Tags: javascript, python, csv, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am developing a heart rate sensor app where the readings are being stored in a CSV file.
The mobile app communicates with the Raspberry pi via bluetooth.
I am using ssh on VSCode to develop on the Raspberry Pi.
When the Python code is run on its own directly, a CSV is created, the sensor starts up and readings are saved.

But when I try to kick off the python code as a child process in Javascript, the code gets to creating the CSV file before it is killed without an error output.
In addition, the PID that is created from starting the child process does not appear in the Raspberry Pi task manager.

I need the code to work that when "1" is passed on a BLE app the python process begins and the readings are stored in a CSV.

The issue seems to be with creating and writing to a CSV file, as i have tried to take that part out so that the results are just printed to console, and that worked fine.

Javascript:

```js
 function startLogging() { 

     if (! pythonProcess)
     {
         pythonProcess = spawn('python',["/home/pi/github/little_pulse/little_pulse/code/pulse_sensor/pulseWriter.py"]);

     };

 };


loggingCharacteristic.prototype.onWriteRequest = function(data,
    offset, withoutResponse, callback) {

     if(!offset) {
         this._value = data;
     }

     console.log('loggingCharacteristic - onWriteRequest: value = ' +
     this._value.slice(offset, offset + bleno.mtu).toString()
   );

   if( this._value == 1)
   {
     console.log('Logging Started');
     sensor.startLogging();
   }

   else if(this._value == 2)
   {
     sensor.stopLogging();
     console.log('Logging Stopped');
   }

   else {
     console.log('Incorrect Input');
   }


   callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, this._value);
 };
```

Python:

```py
from pulsesensor2 import Pulsesensor

import csv

p = Pulsesensor()

    with open('/home/pi/github/little_pulse/little_pulse/heartRateCSV.csv',n'a', newline='') as f:

        theWriter = csv.writer(f)
        theWriter.writerow(['Time','BPM','col3'])    #column names
        try:

              p.startAsyncBPM()
              while True:
                     #Code that prints bpm to console and writes to csv
        except:
            p.stopAsyncBPM()
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. possibly?

Comment: I've gone on the raspberry pi and have given everything permission to read, write, execute the python code and allowed access to an already created CSV file, no change.